# Salesforce Standard API - Content Version

Tags: api, governorlimits, contentversion

I'm trying to send an array of content versions via the Standard API that Salesforce suggests :

Using POST method to :

https://SandboxName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ContentVersion

```
[
 {
  "VersionData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABADn/2Q==",
  "PathOnClient":"Array1.jpg",
  "Description":"Array1",
  "Document_Type__c":"1"

 },

 {
  "VersionData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgh25==",
  "PathOnClient":"Array2.jpg",
  "Description":"ARRAy2",
  "Document_Type__c":"1"
 }
]
```

With one file - Its working, but when I change it to array and add another file - Its throw me this error :

```
**[
    {
        "message": "Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]**
```

**My questions are:**

1. What the problem here???
2. I'm sending the request ok? and if I do - this is legal to do? (send it as an array).
3. There are limitations that I need to be aware of using an array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are following can insert only one record. In order to create record in bulk using REST API, you need to use Composite Tree resource- Tree resource can be used to create nested records, you can also create multiple, unrelated records of the same type.

So endpoint would be:
https://SandboxName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/**composite/tree**/ContentVersion

Request Body:

```
{"records" :[
 {
  "attributes" : {"type" : "ContentVersion", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
  "VersionData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABADn/2Q==",
  "PathOnClient":"Array1.jpg",
  "Description":"Array1"
 },

 {
  "attributes" : {"type" : "ContentVersion", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
  "VersionData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgh25==",
  "PathOnClient":"Array2.jpg",
  "Description":"ARRAy2"
 }
]
}
```

**P.S: 
In each row you would need to pass a reference id for each record as shown above.**

SOURCE ARTICLE: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

Comment: The Composite resource would also work in this situation.

Comment: @Ayub Is there any Limitation (I guess there are) on the size of the sum of all the contentVersions that I created?
What is the Max size that I can handle with?
Thnkas

Comment: You cannot exceed the payload limit...I'm not sure how much it is 3mb or 6mb but it's fact there is limit and you need to take care of that....especially while uploading files via api...

Comment: @Ayub In SF docs - They wrote that I can upload a file up to 2 GB (including headers) when uploaded via REST API - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm&type=5
What am I missing here??
Many Thanks for you help

Comment: It's when you are using salesforce user interface....if you are using api then regardless what you are uploading, api limits will be counted against...

Comment: Hi @Ayub, Sorry for the interruption again about this subject.
I just created 3 files, that sent via API - POST request - 3 files with a total sum of 9 MB...
I'm still can get it - where the limitation I need to be aware of?
Thanks again

Comment: Hmmm...let me find out help article....meanwhile...would suggest to ask a separate question for this issue...